# Sort through an array, and push duplicates into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects with dates. What I want to do is select all objects with the same date value and push those into a new array.
here's my code.

```
    var posts = [
  {
    "userid": 1,
    "rating": 4,
    "mood": "happy",
    "date": "2017-05-24T04:00:00.000Z"
   },
  {
    "userid": 1,
    "rating": 3,
    "mood": "happy",
     "date": "2017-05-24T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "userid": 1,
    "rating": 3,
    "mood": "angry",
    "date": "2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "userid": 1,
    "rating": 5,
    "mood": "hungry",
    "date": "2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z"
  }]
var may25=[];

for(i=0;i < posts.length;i++){
if(posts[i].date === posts[i].date){
may25.push(posts[i].date)
}
}
```

Comment: So what's not working with your approach. Please take a look at [ask], then provide a **clear problem statement**.

Comment: `if(posts[i].date === posts[i].date)` isn't that always true?

Comment: You have to specify what you want the final value to look like.

Comment: I have multiple objects ive pulled from a database, and i want to push them into arrays based on the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slice the date from the string and take it as key for an object for grouping items by date. The result is an object with all grouped objects.

```js
var posts = [{ userid: 1, rating: 4, mood: "happy", date: "2017-05-24T04:00:00.000Z" }, { userid: 1, rating: 3, mood: "happy", date: "2017-05-24T04:00:00.000Z" }, { userid: 1, rating: 3, mood: "angry", date: "2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z" }, { userid: 1, rating: 5, mood: "hungry", date: "2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z" }],
    groups = Object.create(null);
    
posts.forEach(function (o) {
    var date = o.date.slice(0, 10);
    groups[date] = groups[date] || [];
    groups[date].push(o)
});

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for may 25 dates (as your question suggests):

```
var may25=[];

for (i=0;i < posts.length;i++) {
    if (posts[i].date === "2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z") {
        may25.push(posts[i].date)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create an object that contains date => event arrays :

```
var result=posts.reduce((obj,event)=>((obj[event.date]=obj[event.date] || []).push(event),obj),{});
```

Now you can do:

```
result["2017-05-25T04:00:00.000Z"].forEach(console.log);
```

How it works:

```
posts.reduce((obj,event)=>...,{}) //iterate over the posts and pass each as event to the function and also pass an object to be filled

(obj[event.date]=obj[event.date] || [])//return the date array, or create a new one if it doesnt exist

.push(event)//append our event to it
```